# Elasticsearch - searching wildcard using n-gram

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search, n-gram

I'm having a requirement where the user would type in some characters and expects to get the results similar to SQL like query. I'm using n-gram because I saw lots of people recommend to avoid using a wildcard search. However, the return data sometimes is extremely irrelevant as it contains the characters in the text but mixed up. I added score but it doesn't work. Does anyone have any suggestion? Thanks.

**Updates**

Below is the index settings:

```
"settings": {
    "index": {
        "lifecycle": {
            "name": "audit_log_policy",
            "rollover_alias": "audit-log-alias-test"
        },
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "abi_analyzer": {
                    "tokenizer": "n_gram_tokenizer"
                }
            },
            "tokenizer": {
                "n_gram_tokenizer": {
                    "token_chars": [
                        "letter",
                        "digit"
                    ],
                    "min_gram": "3",
                    "type": "ngram",
                    "max_gram": "10"
                }
            }
        },
        "number_of_shards": "1",
        "number_of_replicas": "1",
        "max_ngram_diff": "10",
        "max_result_window": "100000"
    }
}
```

And here's how the field is mapped:

```
"resourceCode": {
    "type": "text",
    "fields": {
        "ngram": {
            "analyzer": "abi_analyzer",
            "type": "text"
        },
        "keyword": {
            "ignore_above": 256,
            "type": "keyword"
        }
    }
},
"logDetail": {
    "type": "text",
    "fields": {
        "ngram": {
            "analyzer": "abi_analyzer",
            "type": "text"
        },
        "keyword": {
            "ignore_above": 8191,
            "type": "keyword"
        }
    }
}
```

And here's how I will query:

```
query_string: {
    fields: ["logDetail.ngram", "resourceCode.ngram"],
    query: data.searchInput.toLowerCase(),
}
```

**Samples**

Here's the sample query:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "terms": {
                        "organizationIds": [
                            ...
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "range": {
                        "createdAt": {
                            "gte": "2020-08-11T17:00:00.000Z",
                            "lte": "2020-08-31T16:59:59.999Z"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "multi_match": {
                        "fields": [
                            "logDetail.ngram",
                            "resourceCode.ngram"
                        ],
                        "query": "0004"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "sort": [
        {
            "createdAt": "desc"
        }
    ],
    "track_scores": true,
    "size": 20,
    "from": 0
}
```

And here's an irrelevant score

```
{
    "_index": "user-interaction-audit-log-test-000001",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "ae325b4a6b45442cbf8a44d595e9a747",
    "_score": 3.4112902,
    "_source": {
        "logOperation": "UPDATE",
        "resource": "CUSTOMER",
        "resourceCode": "Htest11211",
        "logDetail": "<div>Updated Mobile Number from <var isolate><b>+84966123451000<\/b><\/var> to <var isolate><b>+849<\/b><\/var><\/div>",
        "organizationIds": [
            "5e72ea0e4019f01fad0d91c9",
        ],
        "createdAt": "2020-08-20T08:13:36.026Z",
        "username": "test_user",
        "module": "PARTNER",
        "component": "WEB_APP"
    },
    "sort": [
        1597911216026
    ]
}
```

Comment: You should maybe show what you've tried so far and provide a case to reproduce what you're seeing.

Comment: Hi @Val, if I do a search of `0004` would result in  `C-200820-01` in the results for instance. I'm having a min_gram of 3 and max_gram of 10.

Comment: Please show your setup (index settings, mappings, analyzers, etc). Concrete code is worth a thousand words

Comment: Hi @Val, I have updated as per

Comment: You're not using the `*.ngram` subfields in your query, why?

Comment: Hi @Val, copied the wrong piece of code when I was trying to do a standard match, updated

Comment: I could not reproduce your case with the above information. Searching for `0004` doesn't yield `C-200820-01`

Comment: Hi @Val, I have added a sample. The desired behaviour would be the same as the SQL like query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you don't have [specified any search analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/specify-analyzer.html#specify-search-analyzer). So your search input also gets analyzed by the `abi_analyzer` and `0004` gets tokenized into `000` and `004`. The former token, i.e. `000` matches one token of the `logDetail.ngram` field.

What you need to do is to specify a `standard` `search_analyzer` for both fields in your mapping so that you don't analyze your search input but simply try to match it with the same indexed tokens:

```
"resourceCode": {
    "type": "text",
    "fields": {
        "ngram": {
            "analyzer": "abi_analyzer",
            "search_analyzer": "standard",           <--- here
            "type": "text"
        },
        "keyword": {
            "ignore_above": 256,
            "type": "keyword"
        }
    }
},
"logDetail": {
    "type": "text",
    "fields": {
        "ngram": {
            "analyzer": "abi_analyzer",
            "search_analyzer": "standard",           <--- here
            "type": "text"
        },
        "keyword": {
            "ignore_above": 8191,
            "type": "keyword"
        }
    }
}
```

If you don't want to change your mapping because you don't want to reindex your data, you can also specify the search analyzer at query time:

```
            {
                "multi_match": {
                    "fields": [
                        "logDetail.ngram",
                        "resourceCode.ngram"
                    ],
                    "analyzer": "standard",          <--- here
                    "query": "0004"
                }
            }
```

**UPDATE**:

```
        "analyzer": {
            "abi_analyzer": {
                "tokenizer": "n_gram_tokenizer"
                "filter": ["lowercase"]
            }
        },
```

Comment: Hi @Val, I was wondering whether the search input is tokenized. Reindexed and works like a charm. Upvoted, thank you.

Comment: Hi @Val, may I ask why for n-gram tokenized field `N000331a` with the same settings and mappings, query `0331a` would work but `N000331a` wouldn't

Comment: You're probably missing a lowercase token filter. The `standard` tokenizer lowercases everything, so at search time `N000331a` gets tokenized as `n000331a` and that wouldn't match the index-time token `N000331a`. See my updated answer

Comment: Well I do a toLowerCase() for every search input so `N000331a` would become `n000331a` when it comes to the query

Comment: Regardless of the `toLowerCase()` at search time, the problem is not search time, but index time. Please read my comment again